# PLSQL:Can oracle variable of record type can be created at run time

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE 
LV_COL_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
LV_QUERY VARCHAR2(4000);

  type cur is ref cursor;
  select_cur cur;

  type rec is select_cur%rowtype;
  LT_REC rec;


BEGIN 


SELECT COL_NAME INTO LV_COL_NAME FROM TEST; --contains column info of emp table.

  cursor select_cur
  for 'SELECT '||LV_COL_NAME||'
       FROM HMCNSPROD.HM_CONSUMER WHERE ROWNUM=1';

  fetch select_cur bulk collect INTO LT_REC;    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LT_REC: '||LT_REC.count); 
  close select_cur;        


EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||SQLERRM); 
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Abhijeet. What is the error message that you are getting, maybe that can make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `%rowtype` declaration for a ref-cursor. Maybe it works for a "strong" defined ref-cursor but I did not test.

A strong declaration looks like this one:

`type recis ref cursor return HMCNSPROD.HM_CONSUMER%rowtype;`